# The Forbidden Fruit : Figure of speech

Tags: figures-of-speech, contemporary-english

Simply put, I'd like to know what figure of speech we can classify the phrase "forbidden fruit" under. 
I've searched online and couldn't find anything concise.

Comment: In the normal usage, actual fruit is not involved, so this is a metaphor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: One could say the original biblical forbidden fruit was "knowledge" itself (since it came from "the tree of knowledge", as I recall).  But per [Cambridge Dictionaries,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forbidden-fruit) it's now defined as *something, **especially something sexual,** that is even more attractive because it is not allowed.* In which context I note *[strange] fruit* (often associated with non-hetero sexuality). And there's also *fruity = risqué, indecent, suggestive, racy, blue, sexy, ripe, spicy.* Fruit is ***hot**!*

Comment: Such metaphore is an"allegory" (a representation of an abstract or spiritual meaning through concrete or material forms; figurative treatment of one subject under the guise of another).

Comment: @FF The only reasonable explanation I've heard was that it was real fruit from a real tree, and that disobeying the one then given law was tantamount to man asserting that he himself was entitled and competent to be the final arbiter in evaluating good and evil.

Comment: While most associate the fruit Eve gave to Adam as an apple, Biblical scholars usually associate it with the banana and its related imagery linked to the phallus.

Comment: No fruit was ever forbidden. It was the tree itself that was not to be partaken of, in the garden. There is no fruit on that tree, as became evident after _the tree_ was assimilated. [Genesis 3:1](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/1003001). It is a question of how humanity functions - either by partaking of knowledge (externally to Deity) or partaking of Life (Deity himself).

Comment: @Nigel J As the OP, i mean the phrase "forbidden fruit" in the literal sense. So i wasn't thinking solely biblical when i asked the question. By the way Gen 3:3: "But OF THE FRUIT OF THE TREE WHICH [IS] IN THE MIDST OF THE GARDEN, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.... So the fruit was actually forbidden" even though the fruit was never named. But modern movie directors like to portray the fruit as an Apple.

Comment: @Light You are quoting Eve's words. I was referring to God's words [Genesis 2:17](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/1002017).

Comment: Same thing if you ask me, Gen 2:17 "But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, THOU SHALT NOT EAT OF IT: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die." You don't eat a tree, you eat its produce, so God was still referring to the fruit. I'm sure if Eve had boiled the branch of the tree for herbs, she would still be within the commandment.

Comment: The question shows scant research and even scarcer detail. Please tell us which rhetoric devices you have discarded and why.

Comment: One of your comments notes that you’re asking about the phrase in the *literal sense*. In that case, there is no figure of speech involved.

Answer (score 0):

**forbidden fruit** - a metaphorical phrase  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/forbidden-fruit)

> something very nice that you want very much but are not allowed to
>   have